# fullcalendar appear after window resize only | angular

Tags: html, css, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I installed fullCalendar in my project but the calendar appears only when screen is resized.

[image]

I added this code in home.module.ts

```
import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular'; // the main connector. must go first
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'; // a plugin
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'; // a plugin


FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([ // register FullCalendar plugins
  dayGridPlugin,
  interactionPlugin
]);

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ....
    FullCalendarModule, // for FullCalendar!
   ....


  ],
```

In home.page.ts i added following code

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core'; // include this line
import { CalendarOptions  } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'; // a plugin
export class HomePage {

  calendar = Calendar;
  calendarVisible = false;

  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin],
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    // initialView: 'dayGridWeek'
  };

  constructor() {
    // const name = Calendar; // add this line in your constructor

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.calendarVisible = true;
  }
```

After this i added simple html from there guide to angular component page.

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <full-calendar *ngIf="calendarVisible" [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>


</ion-content>
```

there are no css its bare minimum setup.

Comment: A picture is useful, but we can't fix pictures. We would also need to see enough code to be able to reproduce the problem

Comment: Hi @ADyson  i just updated the question please take a look

Comment: what do you mean "there are no css"? fullCalendar has at least one CSS file you must include, and some of the plugins also add extra ones. This may be handled by your build system, but perhaps you need to verify it, because you clearly have a problem.

Comment: @ADyson it adds css automatically once we add library as instructed in there doc. "There are no css" means i have not implemented any custom css till now. also once i resize window it fits perfect and all days everything appears as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Adding it in the ionViewWillEnter life cycle did the trick for me.

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions;

ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.calendarOptions = {
      height: 'auto',
      headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,listWeek'
      },
      
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      initialDate: new Date(),
      
    };
  }
```

Comment: Note that this only works in pages, because plain (Angular) components do not have that lifecycle event. You can make a workaround with setTimeout though or you need to notify the component when the parent page has finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

I used setTimeout to load calendarOptions and it worked for me.

calendarOptions: CalendarOptions;

setTimeout(() => {
this.calendarOptions= {
initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
...
};
},1);

Comment: but it looks as workaround, it doesn't explain why it actually doesn't appear before window resize and do not guaranty that it works in 100%

Answer (score -1):

I also had a similar situation for which that I rendered the entire calendar again and it worked.